# Detecting Google MyBusiness deleted reviews

Tags: google-my-business-api

We use Google My Business API for synchronising and managing Google Reviews.

Whenever there is a new review we can pick this up by querying the api and checking for the UpdateTime.  We compare this with the last update we recorded in our database.  In theory this should give us a copy of all of the reviews as they are added and updated.

We retrieve the reviews with a call to

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/[location.Name]/reviews?pageSize=200

We then step through the reviews and compare the UpdateTime with the last recorded update in our database.

```
if (((DateTime)review.UpdateTime).ToString() > lastReviewUpdate.ToString())
{
   //Add or update the review
}
```

My question is what happens if a Reviewer removes their review?

Does the API show this as an updated Review?  Is it still provided when we query the api?  How do we detect it?

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: @Can No sorry - haven't touched it for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran an experiment with a live review site.

I added a review.

This showed up in Mybusiness and I synchronised it OK.

I then deleted the review.

When the API ran with

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/[location.Name]/reviews?pageSize=200

The review had just disappeared.

So it appears the list function anyway does not cater for deleted reviews.  The only way to manage a synchronisation process is to compare all the reviews that have been synchronised with all of the reviews in GMB via the list function.

Not ideal but I suppose it is a solution.

Comment: The problem is that GMB is not so accurate returning the reviews list. every time I execute my code I have different number of reviews in a way that my comparing function might tag a review as deleted, and once more they are back.